# How to get index value of a set array in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

If I have a DataFrame with a column showing a set array, how do I get specific values in the set array?

df:

```
0    Array
1    {878,999,858}
```

Desired:

```
1st index: 878
2nd index: 999
3rd index: 858
```

What I tried:

```
df['Array'].values[0]
>> {878,999,858}
```

When I tried to add `df['Array'].values[0].index.values[2]` to get 2nd index, it doesn't allow me to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: `set` is unordered so there is no meaning of `index`

Comment: Sets aren't ordered objects, so it doesn't make sense to index them by order. There is no guarantee that placing three items into the set will result in them being shown in the same order. If you just want the elements, you can convert to a list and index into that, but be aware that the order may change.

Comment: Ordering doesn't really matter at this point, really just trying to reduce the values to 1 items in the set

Comment: if it is list you can use `df['Array'].str[1]` for second index

Comment: `Ordering doesn't really matter at this point`, then how are you defining `2nd index`. There is no `2nd index` in `set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have better ways to do it but...

### Creating test dataframe

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [{878,999,858}]})
```

### Printing dataframe

```
>>> df
                 A
0  {858, 878, 999}
```

### Printing row 0

```
>>> df.loc[0]["A"]
{858, 878, 999}
```

### Printing row 0 as a list

```
>>> list(df.loc[0]["A"])
[858, 878, 999]
```

### Getting each item

```
>>> list(df.loc[0]["A"])[0]
858
>>> list(df.loc[0]["A"])[1]
878
>>> list(df.loc[0]["A"])[2]
999
```

Comment: suppose in my computer the set is `{ 878, 858, 999}` so the result will be `878, 858,999` instead `858, 878, 999`.